# Kendo UI login functionality

Tags: javascript, php, html, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am currently making a iPhone application using Kendo UI which i am running through phone gap to test on my iPhone.

The design is all mapped out nicely and I am getting to grips with the Kendo framework. I am trying to make some functionality whereby they log into an account.

My external PHP file which runs the query and returns JSON:

```
<?php

   $arr = array();

//Takes the username and password from the login form and queries the database to find out if they have access to the site.


        //Cleanse inputs
        $username = $_GET['username'];
        $password = md5_base64($_GET['password']);

        $stmt = $memberMysqli->prepare("SELECT id, firstname, dob, sex, recordingWeight, blocked, enabled FROM member WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($memberid, $firstname, $dob, $sex, $recordingWeight, $blocked, $enabled);
        $stmt->store_result();  

        session_start();

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            $userIsBlocked = $blocked;
            $enabled = $enabled;
        }   

        if(($numRows = $stmt->num_rows) > 0)  //If num rows is  1 the combination exists therefore it is a succesful login
        {   
            if($userIsBlocked)
            {
                $arr['status'] = "error";
                $arr['message'] = "Sorry, your account isnt active. Please contact us to re-activate it.";
            }
            else if(!$enabled)
            {
                $arr['status'] = "error";
                $arr['message'] = "Sorry, your account isn't enabled. Please contact us.";
            }

            else
            {
                    $_SESSION['memberid'] = $memberid;
                    $_SESSION['memberFirstname'] = $firstname;
                    $_SESSION['dob'] = $dob;
                    $_SESSION['sex'] = $sex;
                    $_SESSION['recordingWeight'] = $recordingWeight;

                    $arr['status'] = "success";
                    $arr['message'] = "Logged in";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $arr['status'] = "error";
            $arr['message'] = "Sorry, Wrong Username/Password Combination";                 
        }
header("Content-type: application/json");   
echo json_encode($arr);
/* close connection */
function md5_base64 ( $data ) 
{ 
    return preg_replace('/=+$/','',base64_encode(md5($data,true))); 
} 


?>
```

So this returns success, logged in or sorry wrong username/password combination..

Here is my form code:

```
<form>

            <fieldset>

                <p><label style="color:white;" for="email">E-mail address</label></p>
                <p><input type="email" id="email" value=""></p> 

                <p><label style="color:white; font" for="password">Password</label></p>
                <p><input type="password" id="password" value=""></p> 

                <p><input type="submit" value="Sign In"></p>

            </fieldset>
```

and the JS:

```
<script>

        $("form").on("submit", function() {

        var username = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
          transport: {
            read:  {
             url: 'http://myurl.co.uk/appqueries/login.php?username='+username+'&password='+password,
             dataType: "json" 
          }
          }
        });

        //alert("Your username is "+username+" and your password is: "+password);

        });
    </script>
```

Can anybody help me getting what the JSON that the PHP file returns and then letting the user into the app if login is successful, or displaying a message if they were not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want a DataSource for this (it could be done, but the DataSource expects an array of objects from the read operation), unless there are additional requirements.

If this is your HTML:

```
<input id='username' type='text' value='user'></input>
<input id='password' type='text' value='password'></input>
<button id='loginbutton'>Login</button>
<div id='loginresult'></div>
```

Then you can use jQuery (which I assume you're using since it's a requirement for Kendo UI):

```
function loginClick() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var loginUrl = 'http://myurl.co.uk/appqueries/login.php?username='+username+'&password='+password;

    $.ajax({
        url: loginUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            handleLoginResult(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).on("click", "#loginbutton", loginClick);

function handleLoginResult(data) {
    var status = data.status;
    var message = data.message;

    if (status === "success") {
        // do whatever needs to be done after successful login
        $("#loginresult").html(message);
    }
}
```

See a working example here (there are a few differences because this is using jsfiddle's echo api): http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/9TGJd/

This works almost the same for Kendo Mobile, except you'd use the mobile button and the data-click binding:

```
  <a id="loginbutton" data-role="button" data-click="loginClick">Login!</a>
```

Comment: i have implemented the login.. but everytime i open the app page it again asks for login. can you tell me how to keep the user logged so that when ever he opens the app he is taken to the homepage from the login page

Answer (score 1):

You should not use form submit in Kendo Mobile application as a Kendo mobile application is basically a Single Page Application. What you need to do is to have a Kendo button and on the click event handler, fire the JSON call. You can see the demo of Kendo Button click event here: http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/button/events.html#/

Comment: Thanks, any idea on how to use the button events with a DB to determine and successful login or not?

Comment: Basically, you fire an ajax call in the button click event. In the ajax call, you can send the user credentials to your backend service. The back-end service will check if the login succeeds or no and return a boolean indicating the status which will be available in ur ajax callback. depending on this value, you can tell user if their login succeeded or not. This is  shown in my Kendo Mobile book, "Building Mobile Applications Using Kendo UI Mobile and ASP.NET Web API". I am planning to upload the code to Git. will send u the link once done.